# celery flower web received and started timezone not in my set time-zone.still UTC time-zone

Tags: celery, flower

I already search same question, but it's different.

the tasks show received time and started time still are UTC time;

the worker config in flower check, timezone is Asia/Shanghai.

in my celery_task config also give already:

```
enable_utc = False
timezone = 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

new version is like this config,not before

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
```

i also try old conf, its same not effective;
i also try run flower command includ: flower -A celery_task
still not effective.
so how can show right time-zone time in web received time and started time?

Answer (score 1):

its not load celery config, the flower start command must use:"celery -A celery_task",the '-A xxxxx' must in 'celery' after, not 'flower' after.
just can right load;

the problem from 'flower\views\tasks.py' 118 row,
'flower\static\js\flower.js' 397 row;